# Do Armor of Agathys and Fire Shield stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, stacking

I have a party of a paladin, rogue, and warlock. The warlock player thinks having only 2 spells per short rest is making him really weak, so he is trying to find the best possible ways to be more useful.

So he is wondering if *armor of Agathys* and *fire shield* stack. I am wondering if he’s just power-gaming, or if this really does work and is the kind of thing a warlock is supposed to do.

Comment: You say the Warlock feels weak; has he been using Hex?

Comment: Warlocks are one of the strongest classes in the game. If he optimizes for _being hit_, he _makes himself_ weak. Using Hex, with two beams of Eldritch Blast per action his DPR should be higher than the Rogue's.

Comment: *Hex* is a Warlock's bread and butter! As @András mentions, *Hex* + *EB* = 2d10+2d6+(CHA w Agonizing Invocation). *Hex* + *Scorching Blast* is up to 9d6.

Answer (score 17):

### They should stack.

Fire Shield states:

> whenever a creature within 5 feet of you hits you with a melee attack,
>   the shield erupts with flame. The attacker takes 2d8 fire damage from
>   a warm shield, or 2d8 cold damage from a cold shield.

Armor of Agathys states:

> You gain 5 temporary hit points for the duration. If a creature hits
>   you with a melee attack while you have these hit points, the creature
>   takes 5 cold damage.

Neither spell is a concentration spell, so they can be cast concurrently. There is nothing in the spell descriptions that would keep them from operating at the same time.

Note however, that both of these are primarily defensive spells, and require you to be hit. I'm not sure how this would make the warlock character "more useful".

Comment: Yeah, this kind of thing is only useful if you can either force enemies to attack you, or you can put enemies in a situation where they really *want* to attack you, with these spells forcing them to choose between two bad options (not attacking you when they really want to, attacking you but taking some damage). Without anything else going on, and barring party assistance making this happen, it seems like the warlock could be safely ignored by the enemy, at least until the rest of the party’s been dealt with.

Comment: Or peppered with missile weapons or ranged spell attacks. Or grappled, which does not require "a hit"

Comment: Our Warlock thinks it would be fun to multiclass so he would get medium armor and martial weapons and run into enemies attacking them with melee and that they would be hittedby his spells.

Comment: I ran a build like that.  It's not for the char-ops types, but definitely very playable.

Comment: @Mira: The fact that he has better weapons and armor is still not going to force enemies to attack *him*. Those spells only work when he is hit, *not* when he hits others.

Answer (score 0):

### They will stack!

As either spell requires simply 1 action and neither is considered a concentration spell, both spells may stack. According to the DMG, as long as you do not cast two concentration spells and/or the spells are not the same, you may stack spells.

Also, you could pair this spell with [Hellish Rebuke](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hellish-rebuke), were you to choose a Tiefling Warlock, as it is considered a reaction.

If your DM allows Unearthed Arcana material, the Hexblade warlock patron's Armor of Hexes feature (from [Unearthed Arcana: Warlock & Wizard](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf)) could also further sway an enemy's desire to hit you if it is cursed by your Hex. Whenever a creature affected by your Hexblade curse would hit you, roll a d6; on a 4 or higher, the attack misses instead.

I'm sure, with a little digging, you could find even more possibilites to combine and further fortify the counter on an enemy's attack. Happy hunting!

Comment: Note: the [Hexblade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheHexblade) patron has since been published in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 55-56). You may want to update your answer accordingly.